# Formula or VBA to find and remove row-wise duplicates but keep column-wise duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, filtering, rows

I have an excel sheet with duplicate entries in rows and columns (See sample below).

I need to eliminate values that appear more than once in each row so that each row is left with only unique values, while keeping the column-wise duplicate values. I have scoured the internet for days but there doesn't seem to be a solution to this anywhere. All I can find are the basic duplicate data elimination techniques which wouldn't work in my case. Any solution will be very much appreciated!

[image: Sample of what I'm trying to get at]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNIQUE()` function with `TRANSPOSE()`.

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(A1:E1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, my comment thanking you got deleted. I am pretty new to this platform so maybe I'm not allowed to say thanks? Anyway, thank you so much again!

Comment: No issue, Once you tick mark the answer, you thanks me. Means, tick marking to the best answer is the way of saying thanks to this community. Glad to know it works.